# How do I write to (invoke) a contract with arguments from Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying to use the [BirthdayGift](https://live.ether.camp/account/9828f591b21ee4ad4fd803fc7339588cb83a6b84) contract within Ethereum Wallet, and am not seeing how to do so. The UI was hidden and with help from Christopher I expanded the window to see the UI for invoking the contract. The problem is I cannot set the two inputs before running it. They are shown in the Read section but I expected them to be editable, and possibly in the Write section.

[image]

I am not attached to this contract, I just want to write to some contract from Ethereum Wallet.

Comment: try making the window bigger the write functions might be hidden for some reason.

Comment: @ChristopherFranko thanks, I can now see it. Will update question with refined question.

Comment: The taken function has no parameters that is why you are not seeing any inputs.

Comment: Ah, thanks. How do I run the BirthdayGift function so I can set the birthdate when I fund it? https://live.ether.camp/account/9828f591b21ee4ad4fd803fc7339588cb83a6b84/contract